# Pawn-free squares

Tags: chess, checkerboard

The chessboard below contains two pawns.

[image]

> How many squares (of any size) does not contain a pawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
5*5: 1
4*4: 6
3*3: 18
2*2: 41
1*1: 62
total: 128
```